# How to sort PubMed API results by "Best Match"

Tags: api, pubmed

When you search for studies on the PubMed website, you can choose to sort by "Best Match", which is a new search algorithm PubMed introduced last year. However, when you try to access studies using PubMed's eSearch API tool, there are no instructions for how to sort your results using "Best Match".

I currently sort by relevance, but this isn't what I want. I want to search with "best match"

```
'sort':'relevance',
```

As an example, a search for "vaccines and autism" on the PubMed website sorting by Best Match yields 2215 results, but using "relevance" in the API, I get less than 100. What do I write instead of "relevance" to get the desired results (2215)?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I spoke to someone at PubMed. They told me they don't make "best match" available through their API. You can only use it if you use the PubMed website.